# Cassandra client port enable

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

How to enable cassandra port to connect with BI application. Here my setup with cassandra is of multiple nodes (192.xxx.xx.01,192.xxx.xx.02,192.xxx.xx.03). In this scenario which node will be acting like master / coordinator with my application.

Although i worked with listen_address, rpc_address, broadcast_rpc_address and seeds, I opened both tcp ports 9042 and 9160.

version: 3.10

Kindly, lead me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra uses master-less architecture.All nodes are equal in cassandra.

When you connect to one of the node that node act as co-ordinator node, any of the node can be co-ordinator.

The coordinator is selected by the driver based on the policy you have set. Common policies are DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy and TokenAware Policy.

For DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy, the driver selects the coordinator node based on its round robin policy. See more here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.html

For TokenAwarePolicy, it selects a coordinator node that has the data being queried - to reduce "hops" and latency. More info: http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/TokenAwarePolicy.html

`native_transport_port` is 9042 by default and clients use native transport by default.

Hence you should have connection from your BI to Cassandra host on port 9042.

Comment: Thanks, I got master-less architecture but struggling with cassandra configuration to connect with client. Here are my conf details. Kindly correct me if im wrong.

`listen_address: 192.xxx.xx.01
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: 192.xxx.xx.01
listen_on_broadcast_address: true`

Comment: can you check whether you can telnet to cassandra host on port 9042 from your BI server

Comment: No, i was not able to telnet.

Comment: you need to open port from your BI server to cassandra host... it might be firewall issue